# Java, add and displaying array of exam score among other detail in a contructor

Tags: java

The simple code below return the user name

```
 public class Name {
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
    
    //Constructor
     public Name(String f, String l) {     
        firstName = f;
         lastName = l;
     }
     //Getter
     public String getFirstname(){return firstName; }
     public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
    
     //Setter
     public void setFirstName(String newFirstname){this.firstName=newFirstname;}
     public void setLastName(String lastName) {this.lastName = lastName; }
    
    public String getDetail() {
         return  firstName+lastName;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Name C1 = new Name("Mary","Smith") ;
     System.out.println(C1.getDetail());
    
     }
    
     }
```

What do i need to do so i can add arrays of exam mark to Name Constructor? say [7,8,6,8,9]

i am trying to change the line

```
   Name C1 = new Name("Mary","Smith") ;
```

to something like

```
   Name C1 = new Name("Mary","Smith", [7,8,6,8,9]);
```

so it print out "MarySmith [7,8,6,8,9]"

I think i should declare `int[] Score = new int[5];`  is instance variable, but i dont know how to add it to constructor and do what i want above. or am i doing it in the complete wrong way?

any help and tips?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new parameter to the constructor accepting the array and store it in an instance variable as:

```
public class Name
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int[] scores;     

    //Constructor
    public Name(String f, String l, int[] s) {     
         firstName = f;
         lastName = l;
         scores = s;
    }
}
```

And in `getDetail`,

```
public String getDetail() {
    return  firstName + " " + lastName + " " + Arrays.toString(scores);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but how would add the arrays of score in? i tried

     Name C1 = new Name("Mary","Smith",[1,2,3,4,6]);

but that doesnt work

Comment: You need to construct your object like this:  Name C1 = new Name("Mary","Smith", new int[]{1,2,3,4,6});